# Start a single color full screen from the terminal

Tags: terminal, x11

For testing displays, I need to show a single color fullscreen, and quickly switch from one to the next color. Can this be done from the terminal?

Something like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0 color #ff0000
```

Comment: you can use `xsetroot` for this purpose, for example: `xsetroot -solid "#ffffff"`. However, it would not show a color in a new window but would change the background screen color and this is probably not what you want. But you can always use `Xephyr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first thought was `xsetroot` but I think that the following `Python` snippet will do it better:

```
import gtk
import sys

def create_window():
    window = gtk.Window()
    window.set_default_size(200, 200)
    window.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
    color = gtk.gdk.color_parse(str(sys.argv[1]))
    window.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, color)

    window.maximize()
    window.show()

create_window()
gtk.main()
```

Usage:

```
$ python window.py '#01fffa'
```

Comment: great idea, but no gtk and py on the device... I should do it with the available basic Linux stuff. xsetroot as Arkadiusz proposed, is a great idea, but only works on one of the two devices I have under test. Will check with my OS colleague if xsetroot can be easily added

Comment: @Frank: what exactly doesn't work with `xsetroot`?

Comment: xsetroot is not installed...