# x11- Set entire screen to single color

Tags: bash, ubuntu, linux-mint, x11, xset

I would like to know how to set the entire screen to a single color (white in my case).

I'm trying to make a primitive wake-up light script (that uses my laptop screen). I would trigger it using cron. I've figured out how to programmatically change the backlight [1] and now I want to display a full white screen.

I've tried `xsetroot -solid "#ffffff"` as suggested in [Start a single color full screen from the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195910/start-a-single-color-full-screen-from-the-terminal+) but it had no visible effect. I've also tried using `xset s blank`, again with no effect. Neither of them changed the desktop background.

I would prefer not to use python, to keep things slim.

Are there some arguments I'm missing for `xsetroot`? Preferably I'd also like to turn the entire screen white, not just the background, but the latter works as well. Or maybe `xset` can create an entirely white fullscreen screensaver? Couldn't find any `xset` command that would do that.

The DE I'm using is Cinnamon 5.2.7, on Linux Mint 20.3 if that's relevant.

[1] write 19200 into `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Comment: Does `xsetroot -gray` change the root color to gray? How about `xsetroot -solid white`?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the desktop background. It does not change at all. I've also tried setting it to a solid color via the GUI, then running xsetroot, but still, neither of those commands have an effect.

Comment: Yes, ["root window" = "desktop background" in X11 parlance](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/xorgproto/-/blob/master/specs/xproto/glossary.xml#L976). What is the exit code of `xsetroot` when you run it with valid options (like in my comment)? Also, what user are you running `xsetroot` as?

Comment: The exit code of both `xsetroot -gray` and `xsetroot -solid white` are 0. I'm running it as a regular user (not with `sudo` - but that doesn't seem to work either).

Comment: Ok, I just realized you said you were using Cinnamon. It's in charge of the root window and is preventing `xsetroot`. If you were to use no display manager, or a simpler one like twm, this would work. Cinnamon is based on GNOME, so make a large, all white PNG and try: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///tmp/all-white.png`.

Comment: @bishop You might want to post that as  an answer. Feel free to copy my answer as an introduction if you like; please ping me so that I can delete mine then.

Answer (score 3):

In modern desktop environments, the desktop environment is responsible for displaying a background image, essentially on top of the bare X11 desktop background.

In other words, `xsetroot` will basically appear to fail; you will need to use the desktop nevironment's settings to control the actual visible background.

Answer (score 2):

[tripleee](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/19240/tripleee) explained why `xsetroot` failed in your setup, so I'll outline options you have to achieve the stated objective:

> turn the entire screen white, not just the background

There are three situations to account for:

1. Your screen has turned off, due to inactivity
2. Your screen is on and the screen saver is running
3. Your screen is on, your desktop is visible, and zero or more applications are visible

For situation #1, consider `rtcwake` or any of the APM subsystem tools to goad your system awake at the desired time. You might also have to do `acpi=off apm=off` at the kernel command line, or use `gsettings` to adjust GNOME understanding of power management. Just note that there are many different power management subsystems: GNOME, X Server, kernel, firmware, and hardware. All of them have to be in agreement so this may be fiddly.

For situation #2, you can use `pkill` to terminate any `xscreensaver` processes currently running. On GNOME based systems, there may be `gnome_screensaver`, in which case you'll need to check for that (and `pkill` if so).

Finally, for situation #3, you want to draw a window over all other that is white. The way that comes to mind is with `xv -root all-white.png`, making sure to pass Xresource values to maximize the window.